# Opening a file with CreateFile() returns invalid handle with error code 183

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio, winapi, createfile

I'm trying to open an existing file and write its content to a newly created file as a stream:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h> 

#define BUFFER_LENGTH 2048 

int main(void) {
        BYTE    buffer[BUFFER_LENGTH];
        DWORD   readCount;
    
        // Program breaks here.
        HANDLE hReadFile = CreateFile(L"file.mp4", GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
        if (hReadFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {        
            printf("Error: %d\n", GetLastError());
            return 1;
        }
    
        HANDLE hWriteFile = CreateFile(L"out.mp4", GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
        if (hWriteFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
            printf("Error: %d\n", GetLastError());
            CloseHandle(hReadFile);
            return 1;
        }
    
        while (ReadFile(hReadFile, buffer, BUFFER_LENGTH, &readCount, NULL) && readCount > 0) {
            if (!WriteFile(hWriteFile, buffer, BUFFER_LENGTH, &readCount, NULL)) {
                CloseHandle(hReadFile);
                CloseHandle(hWriteFile);
                printf("Error: %d\n", GetLastError());
                return 1;
            }
            memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
        }
    
        CloseHandle(hReadFile);
        CloseHandle(hWriteFile);
        return 0;
    }
```

And the program exits with as `CreateFile()` returns an invalid handle. The error code is 183, as per [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-) `(ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS: Cannot create a file when that file already exists.)`.

Then I checked the result after comparing each handle individually:

```
HANDLE hReadFile = CreateFile(L"file.mp4", GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
HANDLE hWriteFile = CreateFile(L"out.mp4", GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

BOOL isInvalid_hRead = hReadFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
BOOL isInvalid_hWrite = hWriteFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
```

I put a breakpoint after these statements and this is the values of the variables:
[image]

Why does the program throw this kind of error when I'm trying to open a file.

**Edit:** I navigated to the folder where the output executable is and ran it, and it worked as expected. But if I run the application from Visual Studio, the invalid handle returns.

Comment: Wild guess: try to replace `CreateFile` with `CreateFileW`.

Comment: Presumably that's not your real code. Please show your real code.

Comment: The 'error' 183 isn't a real error. It is more an informative code that advice you about the existence of that file before you overwrited it, using `CREATE_ALWAYS`, or open it using `OPEN_ALWAYS`. In any case the function don't returns an invalid handle. In case of failure other than error code 183 is returned. Show more of your code if you want a real answer.

Comment: @Frankie_C the OP is opening an _existing_ file for reading, not _creating_ a new one.

Comment: @YashojaLakmith your code is fine, at least it runs fine here. There are just two minor problems: 1: `WriteFile(hWriteFile, buffer, BUFFER_LENGTH, &readCount, NULL)` should be `WriteFile(hWriteFile, buffer, readCount, &readCount, NULL)`, you don't want to write more bytes than you have read. 2: the `memset` is useless, but doesn't harm either.

Comment: @Jabberwocky thank you. I replaced the input file with another one and the issue persists. I'm starting to think that there could be something wrong with the OS's side or some unreleased handle from previous debugging?

Comment: @YashojaLakmith try with some different files. Your code is correct, there is something else unrelated to your code. Also are you sure the code you run is the code you show here? Did you debug this with your debugger?

Comment: @YashojaLakmith `CreateFile` can't **fail** with `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS`. That error code is reported only for `CREATE_ALWAYS` or `OPEN_ALWAYS` as a *success* code, but you are not printing successes, only failures. BTW, if `WriteFile` fails, `CloseHandle` can reset the error code before you print it. Also, you are not printing anything if `ReadFile` fails.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I tried with multiple different files and file types as well as tested the first two if blocks individually.  The handle for write file is valid. But read file is always invalid.

Comment: @YashojaLakmith then what you have shown here must not be your real code, since the code shown won't attempt to open the write handle if the read handle is invalid.

Comment: @RemyLebeau that's why I mentioned that I "individually tested the first two if blocks". I simply commented out the first if block and checked the return value of `hWriteFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` by assigning it into a variable of type `BOOL`. It was always 0, if I did the same with `hReadFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` the value is 1;

Comment: @YashojaLakmith The code you show here works (apart from the minor problems I mentioned before). Add some printfs at relevant places to your code [edit] your question with the new code and show the output. And/or step through your code with the debugger.

Comment: @YashojaLakmith AFAIK, it is simply not possible for `OPEN_EXISTING` to report `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS` if `CreateFile()` fails to open an existing file.

Comment: @YashojaLakmith on a side note, you probably want to use `FILE_SHARE_READ` instead of `FILE_SHARE_WRITE` on `out.mp4`. Other processes should be allowed to *read* what you are writing to it, but not *write* to it while you are still writing to it.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I understood that he is opening an existing file, I was just pointing out that the error code 183 is **never emitted** when an invalid handle is returned, but only set **on success** when using for the `dwCreationDisposition` parameter one of the values `CREATE_ALWAYS` or `OPEN_ALWAYS`, that is not the case here. So the described behavior is completely inconsistent with MS documentation for `CreateFile`.

Comment: Maybe the current directory is not what you think it is. Checkout with [`GetCurrentDirectory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getcurrentdirectory).

Comment: According to the Doc:[CreateFileA function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea)
In my opinion, there is no situation that the function CreateFile returns `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` and GetLastError() returns `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS`(183).
Could you please tell us what version of Windows are you using, and have you tried testing on another computer?

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an answer, but this is a version that displays more information and with some corrected bugs mentioned in the comments.

Run this under your Visual Studio and show us the verbatim output you get.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h> 

#define BUFFER_LENGTH 2048 

int main(void) {
  BYTE    buffer[BUFFER_LENGTH];
  DWORD   readCount;
  int rv = 0;

  printf("Test Program\n");
  WCHAR currentdir[_MAX_PATH];
  GetCurrentDirectory(_MAX_PATH, currentdir);
  wprintf(L"Current dir: %s\n", currentdir);

  HANDLE hReadFile = CreateFile(L"file.mp4", GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
  if (hReadFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    DWORD err = GetLastError();
    printf("Error %d opening input file.\n", err);
    return 1;
  }

  HANDLE hWriteFile = CreateFile(L"out.c", GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
  if (hWriteFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    DWORD err = GetLastError();
    printf("Error %d opening output file.\n", err);
    CloseHandle(hReadFile);
    return 1;
  }

  do
  {
    if (!ReadFile(hReadFile, buffer, BUFFER_LENGTH, &readCount, NULL))
    {
      DWORD err = GetLastError();
      printf("Error %d while reading file.\n", err);
      rv = 1;
      break;
    }
    
    if (readCount > 0)
    {
      DWORD writeCount;
      if (!WriteFile(hWriteFile, buffer, readCount, &writeCount, NULL)) {
        DWORD err = GetLastError();
        printf("Error %d while writing file.\n", err);
        rv = 1;
        break;
      }

      if (readCount != writeCount)
      {
        printf("readCount (%d) is different from writeCount (%d). This is unlikely to happen.\n", readCount, writeCount);
      }
    }
  } while (readCount);

  CloseHandle(hReadFile);
  CloseHandle(hWriteFile);
  return rv;
}
```